# Hosted CMS providers

Tags: hosting, cms

I want to create advanced websites but don't want to use code them myself.

Are there good hosted variants where you can create your website (for a restaurant) in minutes?

Answer (score 2):

No, because you don't specify your understanding of `advanced`.

Yes, because there are dozens if not hundreds of providers out there that install Typo3, Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal etc. in minutes for you. All CMS' that are said to be *advanced.*

Answer (score 0):

take a look into squarespace.com they have their own cms suite with a web out of the box feature.  price is very affordable.  I recently engaged with them on a seperate project and they seem to have a very strong service available.

Answer (score 0):

the most popular nowadays is wordpress. Take a look at wordpress.com